# How come my attempts to enable SOAP for PHP on my mac are not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, configuration, soap

I'm running a PHP site on my local MacBook Pro, which requires Soap.  I went to /usr/local/src/php-5.2.11/ext/soap, and ran "make install".  It completed successfully.  I went to the /usr/local/src/php-5.2.11/ folder, and ran ./configure with many options including --enable_soap.

When I go to http://localhost/phpinfo, it does not list --enable_soap in the Configure Command.

If I add "extension=soap.so" to my /etc/php.ini, then I get this warning when I run php:

```
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './soap.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried restarting apache, which didn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?  Help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say anything about installing fink or macports or installing a separate apache/php installation so I guess you tried that with the default install on OS X. This isn't going to work, as Apple delivers a customized version of this stuff and you can't add modules to it.

What you have to do is to deactivate the default apache in System Preferences->Sharing->Web Sharing and then install your own stack with either [fink](http://fink.sf.net) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) (with MacPorts you can just add the package php5-soap). Other options might be [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or installing directly from source, which is likely quite involved.